# Selenium webdriver select element "next to" already selected element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Hi i'm using selenium on Java and here's the situation:

```
<article><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="link"><img width="150" height="150" src="//somelink.jpg" alt="Qxvd 81gof8" /></a><h1><a class="name-link" href="something">THE NAME I"M USING TO FIND THIS ELEMENT</a></h1><p><a class="name-link" href="somelink">Colour1</a></p></div></article>
<article><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="somelink"><img width="150" height="150" src="someotherlink.jpg" alt="S83glqvbtt8" /></a><h1><a class="name-link" href="link">THE SAME NAME I"M USING</a></h1><p><a class="name-link" href="">Colour2</a></p></div></article>
```

so what i wanna do is to click on the item with colour2 in it. for now i'm just clicking on the first item on the site by searching for the name of element "THE NAME I"M USING TO FIND THIS ELEMENT"  like that

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(., 'THE NAME I"M USING TO FIND THIS ELEMENT')]]")).click();
```

Comment: What is the issue? which element exactly do you want to click?

Comment: i wanna click one that contains "Colour2"

Comment: Why not use By.linxText?

Comment: because I have more than one linktext that contains "colour2" and it will alwyas select the first one.
Now i make a list of elements containing  "THE NAME I'M USING TO FIND THIS ELEMENT" 
like this    `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(., 'THE NAME I'M USING TO FIND THIS ELEMENT')]]")); '`
Now the problem is i can only select it with get by index and i need to select it by colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below XPath for the same

```
//a[text()='Colour2'][../preceding-sibling::h1/a='THE SAME NAME I\"M USING']"
```

So basically we select a link with text `Colour2` which has nearby link with text `THE SAME NAME I"M USING`